# JQuery Click the first one item and the other same class toggle

Tags: jquery, toggle

I want to click the first one item("title1"), and toggle the content next to the other same class.

Can anyone tell me what I should do? Thank you very much.

(My English isn't very good, please don't mind.)

It's my html:

```
<ul>
  <li class="title1"></li>
  <li class="content"></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li class="title1"></li>
  <li class="content"></li>
</ul>
 <ul>
  <li class="title1"><</li>
  <li class="content"></li>
</ul>
```

js:

```
 $(".title1").eq(0).click(function() {
     $(".title1").not(':eq(0)').next(".content").toggle();
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```js
$(".content").toggle();
$(".title1").click(function() {
 $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="title1">title1</li>
  <li class="content">content</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li class="title1">title2</li>
  <li class="content">content</li>
</ul>
 <ul>
  <li class="title1">title3</li>
  <li class="content">content</li>
</ul>
```

When your li elements contains multiple class names then it is best way:

```js
$(".content").toggle();
$("li").click(function(){
$(this).attr("class").split(" ").map((c)=>{ // separate each class name
 /title\d+/.test(c) ? $("."+c).next().toggle() : {}; //check for class names like title1,title(n) if exist then expand next content
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="title1 b">title1</li>
  <li class="content">content</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li class="title1">title1</li>
  <li class="content">content</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li class="title1 e">title1</li>
  <li class="content">content</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li class="title2">title2</li>
  <li class="content">content</li>
</ul>
 <ul>
  <li class="title2">title2</li>
  <li class="content otherclassname">content</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I want only the first "title1" toggle other contents, not every "title1" toggle separately.I am sorry I didn't say it clearly.

Comment: @stargin Means when you click on title1 then toggle all `content`?

Comment: @stargin check new snippet in answer.

Comment: Yes. Toggle all contents. But the content have to base on the same class name. Like: "tittle1" toggle other contents next to "tittle1", "tittle2" toggle other contents next to "title2"...etc

Comment: According to your requirement, you can check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60126282/9071943) to have a better understanding. @stargin

Comment: I have many elements with multiple classes,so it works for me.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it in this way.

```js
$(".title1, .title2").click(function() {
     var className = $(this).attr("class");
     $("." + className).next().toggle();
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="title1">title1</li>
  <li class="content">content</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li class="title2">title2</li>
  <li class="content">content</li>
</ul>
 <ul>
  <li class="title2">title2</li>
  <li class="content">content</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I want only the first "title1" toggle other contents, not every "title1" toggle separately.I am sorry I didn't say it clearly.

Comment: I've just updated my answer, please take a look at @@stargin